# How to deserialize JSON to POJO by JsonPath config

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have the following data
Input:
JsonPath config:

```
{
  fieldA: "$.abc",
  fieldB: "$.bcd"
}
```

json:

```
{
  abc: "ABC",
  bcd: "BCD"
}
```

And expect deserialize POJO:

```
{
  fieldA: "ABC",
  fieldB: "BCD"
}
```

Is it possible or I should implement library which will parse by reflection?

Comment: Reading the documentation rom JsonPath I don't see any serialization features. You need another library for this.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish, either.